# US Customs check External hard disk

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Do US customs check external hard disk? I am worried because I am going to carry data like softwares, ebooks and other things which are illegal according to US laws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

US customs (technically either CBP or ICE) do have the authority to inspect your external hard drive and other electronic devices and there are a few criminal cases based on such searches. But they obviously cannot systematically inspect all devices or HD people carry through the border and would not be primarily looking for illegally downloaded music (if that's what you mean).

[Data obtained by the ACLU](https://www.aclu.org/government-data-about-searches-international-travelers-laptops-and-personal-electronic-devices) suggest that such searches remain exceedingly rare. Obviously, none of this positively guarantees that you won't get in trouble but thousands of people do the same everyday.

Comment: Yup.  I've probably entered the US with various media at least 25 times and never has any of it gotten more scrutiny than a trip through the agriculture x-ray.  On the other hand I've always entered with my wife and hard drives didn't exist the one time I've been in a sex-tourism country.  (When searches do happen it's usually looking for child pornography.)